# Python Merge 2 excel table in row, with not unique key

Tags: python, excel

May I know how to merge 2 excel into 1 like this in python.
I've tried Pandas to merge it by "name" and keep the sequence "index", but no luck. as there are more than 1 location. so, the result should have 2or more location in row.
Many thanks

| index | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | 2 |
| 2 | orange | 3 |
| 3 | grape | 7 |
| 4 | banana | 1 |
| 5 | kiwi | 2.5 |
| 6 | lemon | 1 |

| index | name | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | US |
| 2 | apple | UK |
| 3 | banana | Columbia |
| 4 | banana | Costa Rica |
| 5 | kiwi | Italy |
| 6 | lemon | US |

| index | name | price | location_1 | location_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | 2 | US | UK |
| 2 | orange | 3 | N/A | N/A |
| 3 | grape | 7 | N/A | N/A |
| 4 | banana | 1 | Columbia | Costa Rica |
| 5 | kiwi | 2.5 | Italy |  |
| 6 | lemon | 1 | US |  |

Comment: On which column do you want to merge? The first step would be to import both files in separate pandas dataframes. Maybe try that first and post your code in the question?

Comment: @DSteman, the merge base on name, but keep the existing order. Due to more than 1 product of country , the result should have more than 1 location in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `pd.concat` to combine them.